# Enumeration of partitions of $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If someone asks: *How many abelian groups of order $p^{10}$ are there, up to isomorphism?*

An immediate answer would be *number of partitions of $10$*.

But, if we want to *write down* all these groups/partitions of $10$, then one will do some ad-hoc method of writing it:
$$10, \,\,\,\, 9+1, \,\,\,\, 8+2, \,\,\,\, 8+1+1, \,\,\,\, \ldots$$

My question is, *is there a neat/algorithmic way to write down all partitions of $10$, and in general of any integer $n$?*

Comment: PARI/GP has such a routine, I do not know the concrete algorithm it uses.

Comment: Recursively it's easy. Create a routine that constructs all partitions of n with first part at most m, P(n,m): for all i in 1 to min(n,m) construct P(n-i,min(n-i,m)), then add i to the start of it. I'm not sure that it's the fastest.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it's probably faster to append the last entry than the first from a computational point of view, so construct P(n,m) to have all parts of size at least m, then do the same thing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partition can be seen as a non-decreasing sequence of $n$ non-negative integers with sum equal to $n$.

We can produce them in lexicographic order starting with the smallest which is $1,1,\dots,1$.

To get from one to the next you must look for the rightmost value $a_i$ such there is a positive value to its right and no value to its left is equal to $a_i$, then increase $a_i$ by $1$, and make the values to its right be the smallest possible sequence. I'm not completely sure what the amortized complexity is, but it's pretty fast, to generate the $5$ million partitions of $90$ it takes $10$ seconds in my computer.

Code: https://jorgeferh.xyz/code/genparts.txt